# How to count from were remained using php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WordPress to display some posts in a table and I have a pagination along with this. The table contains a column named "Number" and a column for post title.
My problem is that I don't know how to number every post when I'm on the next page because the number of post starts all over instead of the count where remained. How would I resolve this?

The count it doesn't start from where it should when I go to the next page.
My code:

```html
<?php 
require('wp-load.php');

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $paged = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );
    
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
   
    echo '<table>';
 $count = $paged - 1;
    echo '<tr>
                <td width="100">Number</td>
                <td width="200">Title</td>
          <tr>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
   $count++; 
   //var_dump($count); 
        echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>'.$count .'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.the_title().'</td>';  
        echo '</tr>';
        }
    echo '</table>';
 
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
 echo paginate_links( array(
            'format'       => '?pagina=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, $paged ),
            'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages,
            'prev_next'    => True,
            'prev_text'    => __('Previous'),
            'next_text'    => __('Next'),
        ) ); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$count = (($paged -1) * 2) + 1;
```

where "2" is the *posts_per_page* val.

EDIT: here is the whole code:

```
$count = (($paged -1) * 2) + 1;
echo '<tr>
            <td width="100">Number</td>
            <td width="200">Title</td>
      <tr>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$count .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.the_title().'</td>';  
    echo '</tr>';
    $count++;   
    }
```

Comment: Not working well. The count starts from 2. I want to start the count depending on the page where I am.

Comment: true. Because you ++ it before to use it. Put your $count++ at the end of the while{} loop

Comment: That works. But there is not another way by detecting in the while loop on which page I am and do the count by that parameter?

Comment: Nop. You "detect" the page you are on by the "pagina" GET param and use this number to compute how much post are contained in the previous pages. 
 I've changed my answer as the $count calculation worked only for 2 posts per pages.